# How to stop the termination of the application

Tags: cocoa, macos

I know that my question perhaps sounds a bit confusing, but I want to stop the terminating of a Cocoa Mac Os X application. I don't know if there is an API for that. And I also don't know how to do it.

My idea was to call an `NSAlert` inside the `applicationWillTerminate:` method. But that doesn't stop the termination of the App.

Another possibility would be to use a while loop, which doesn't stop, but this isn't good practice, because it uses a lot of CPU and doesn't add any possibility of keeping the rest of the app running.

Please give me an idea, how I could solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement the application delegate method `applicationShouldTerminate:`. Return either `NSTerminateCancel` or `NSTerminateLater`. If you return `NSTerminateLater` then you should eventually call `replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:` with your final answer.

Comment: Thank you much times, I didn't know about this method. That helped me a lot. =D